# How to automatically .tar a directory once it's moved to a folder

Tags: linux, shell-script, debian, tar

I need an .sh shell/bash script that will automatically tar a directory with the same name of the directory when I move the target directory into another directory (destination directory),

So for example I have directory /home/user/MyFiles/ and I move /MyFiles/ dir inside of /home/user/new/, I need it to create MyFiles.tar inside /home/user/new/ with every file inside /home/user/MyFiles included in the MyFiles.tar.

EDIT: Something I forgot to mention is the directories that I need to .tar sometimes contain the characters () in the directory name so I need the script to take that into account, because I know it gives an error if you don't use the quotes in the tar command and () characters are present, for example tar -cvf "Example-(folder).tar" "Example-(folder)"

Comment: Are you asking for a script to move the directory and create the archive, or are you asking for a service which will watch a directory for newly-created directories and act upon them?

Comment: I'm asking about the first one that you said but now that you mention it. The second script you mentioned would help me a lot as well. So both? Sorry if it's too much to ask.

Comment: Right now I am manually doing the command tar -cvf directory_name.tar directory_name and then I am moving them it over to the destination folder. I would like to just drag a directory into another directory and have it create the tar archive automatically, with the same directory name.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention is the folders that I need to .tar sometimes contain the characters () so I need the script to take that into account, because I know it gives an error if you don't use the quotes in the tar command, for example tar -cvf "Example-(folder).tar" "Example-(folder)"

Comment: Linux don't have folders but *directories*

Comment: Yes, I meant directories when I said folders. I'm new to linux and am trying to learn.

Comment: Your question still lacks motivation. It is unclear (and perhaps you are asking the wrong question). Please **edit your question** to explain, in several paragraphs, why you are asking and your overall goals.

Comment: BTW you won't *drag* files, but you could use `mv` command (or run some program doing a `rename` system call) to move them. Dragging is just a GUI operation (and file can change or be moved/renamed/deleted without any GUI)

Comment: Yes, I know this. I am using Winscp so I can drag directories, with winscp.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities (assuming a native, non-networked, file system like ext4 etc...)

You probably want incron. See e.g. [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-use-incron-monitor-important-files-and-folders). I guess that using `incron` for `IN_CREATE` and `IN_MOVED` events should often be enough. See [incrond(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond) and [incrontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab)

But you should explain your motivations and high-level goals (your question smells badly like some [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)). It seems you want some version control system (or perhaps some backup?). I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Read more about [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Remember that a file (in fact, an inode in a filesytem) can have *several* paths (or none of them) and appear in *several* directories (e.g. using hard links, thru the [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) system call and [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) command).

> I need an .sh shell/bash script that will automatically tar a directory with the same name of the directory when I move the target directory into another directory (destination directory),

This goal is ambiguous (because a file -which is really an anonymous inode- can have *several* names and appear in *several* directories; also a file can be written, created, deleted, truncated and/or read simultaneously by *several* processes).

Perhaps you might run some other script periodically (e.g. with [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), maytbe some cron job running some [make](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/make.1.html) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) command which takes into account the modification time of inodes ....)

<sup>BTW, this site is not a "write my script" service. You should expect hints (like above), not other people to code your own script.</sup>

I recommend reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to understand more your Linux system (from the inside point of view).

P.S. Characters like `(` in filenames are not an issue  (use appropriately double quotes and braces around variable names in your shell scripts). But files and file systems on Linux don't behave like e.g. on Windows. Understanding the notion of inode is essential.

Comment: No. It's my server. I just want to drop a dir, into another dir and have the moved dir become a .tar file with the original dir name as the .tar

Comment: Notice that folders don't really exist on Linux (they are directories), and that a file is mostly an inode (and can have several names, i.e. belong to several directories)

Comment: You need to edit your question to motivate it.

Comment: Yup. I changed folders to directories, to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: But that is not clear enough. You forgot that a file can have *several* names or paths (or even none of them).

Comment: I said that I need the file to have the same name as the directory being moved. For example if I move /Myfiles/ into the destination directory, i need it to become an archive .tar file MyFiles.tar so, whatever the name of the dir, is what I need the .tar to be named.

Comment: But what happens for an i-node accessible thru both `/MyFiles/Foo.txt` and `/HisFiles/Bar.txt` ?

Comment: Yes the ( character is an issue when attempting to .tar a file. You MUST add  quotes "" around the directory and archive filename or else you get following error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('