# What's the correct way to ask for a feature in GNU Linux?

Tags: files, file-format

I'm trying to send a bug report for the app file, /usr/bin/file

But consulting the man and sending an email

> BUGS
>        Please report bugs and send patches to the bug tracker at http://bugs.gw.com/
>        or the mailing list at ⟨file@mx.gw.com⟩ (visit
>        http://mx.gw.com/mailman/listinfo/file first to subscribe).

Made me find out the mail address does not exist.

Is there another way of communicating to the community?
Hopefully this here question is already part of it :)

So here's my email:

> possible feature failure: the `--extension` option doesn't seem to output anything
>
> ```
> $ file --extension "ab.gif" 
> ab.gif: ???
> ```
>
> It would be useful to easily be able to use the output of this to
>   rename a file to its correct extension.
>
> something like file `--likely_extension` would only output the likely
>   detected extension or an error if the detection was too low
>
> like thus:
>
> ```
> $ file --likely_extension "ab.gif"
> gif
> ```
>
> better though would be a `--correct_extension` option:
>
> ```
> $ file --correct_extension "ab.jpg"
>
> $ ls
> ab.gif
> ```
>
> Tyvm for this app :)

Comment: The second part of your problem description is a pure feature request which might run counter to the design philosophy held by some unix tool authors - do one thing only, do it well. Somebody might want to maintain the functionality of file(1) but resent having to maintain builtin basename(1) and mv (1) functionality :)

Comment: Write it........

Comment: You want a feature to do what can already be accomplished using existing commonly supported tools (like awk)?  The software author may be inclined to let you know about, or at least be thinking about, [The Linux Philosophy](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/linus_torvalds_163637).  Once you have a working patch, you'll be taken more seriously.

Comment: In v5.25, `file --extension` *does* work for some file types (like .jpg).  Maybe it doesn't "work" fir .gif because there are no other valid file extensions.

Comment: As an example, on my system: `file --extension calf.jpg flower.gif` outputs: `calf.jpg: jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif` and `flower.gif:` showing the possible other extensions for those files (none in the case of the GIF file). Note that `file` only takes an educated guess at the type of a file - it uses a set of heuristics to do that. It's not detecting the extension from the name. If I rename `calf.jpg` to `calf.txt` it's still a JPEG file and `file` tells me that when I run `file calf.txt` it also tells me that the possible extensions are `jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif` when I run `file --extension calf.txt`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I did the same test. It seems like the bug here is simply the missing data that `.gif` is the typical extension for the `GIF` file type.

Comment: @mattdm: Perhaps not a bug - perhaps by design. I tested `.iso`, `.tgz` and `.png` and none of them output anything either.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Maybe just a very, very incomplete feature?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are following the correct procedure to file an issue or enhancement request: if a program’s documentation mentions how to do so, follow those instructions.

Unfortunately it often happens that projects die, or that the instructions in the version you have are no longer accurate. In these cases, things become a little harder. One possible general approach is to file a bug with your distribution; success there can be rather hit-or-miss though... (I should mention that it’s usually better to report a *bug* to the distribution you got your package from, if you’re using a package; this is especially true if the packaged version is older than the current “upstream” version, and if you haven’t checked whether the issue is still present there.)

For `file` specifically, [the official documentation](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/README) has been updated to mention that the bug tracker and mailing list are down, and it also provides a direct email address for the current maintainer, which you could use to contact him.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440845/50557), you could consider (especially if you are a developer yourself, and if the program – `file` in your case – has source code that is not too difficult to understand) fetching the source code of that program (perhaps from your distribution) - since it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) - and patching it, and also sending a patch.

If you take time to **study the source code**, you'll probably make a better bug report.

If you take more time to **propose a fixing patch**, you are likely to be considered more seriously (and IMHO you are acting more in the spirit of free software).

So **use the freedom provided by [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)**: *study its source code* (freedom#1) and *improve it* (freedom#3).

Today it is very easy to publish (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)) your improved version and *share it* (freedom#2).

Be sure to have the latest release of the `file` program. Many distributions are not using that (and perhaps the bug in your distro has already been fixed upstream).

I am not sure that your `--correct_extension` behavior belongs to `file` (which is a program to *query*, not change, your data). But if it does, it probably should be spelled `--correct-extension` or  `--rename-extension` ... And once you try to implement that, you might discover that there are weird corner cases (what about a gzipped tar file, or a compressed C source file, or something which might need several file extensions).

Notice that (contrary to Windows) on Linux & Unix a file is actually an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (see [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)) and [can have several names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392066/50557) (or none), and can be [opened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_(system_call)) by several processes at once (read about [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)) - or none, even if most files have only one name (but see [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) & [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)). Since the *same* file could be named `foo.txt` and `bar.gz` it does not make a lot of sense to attach importance to file extensions. See also [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).

So, if you try implementing your `correct-extension` idea, you'll find out that it is not that simple to implement (and even to specify), and that there is no obvious simple behavior for that.

**Probably, your idea is not very good, and cannot be easily implemented** on Linux and POSIX systems (at least, not for all cases).

So I recommend to avoid even submitting a feature request (in its initial form, it is a loss of time for you, and for the developers of `file`). Or else, work on it a lot, improve its specifications, and submit a patch.... Of course you'll spend a lot of work on that (and I really don't think it is worth the pain).

Perhaps also read some Unix programming book (like the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf), or something newer; and also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) and [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Comment: How could I forget that — indeed, the best way to “ask” for a feature is to implement it!

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `file` provides information, and does not change anything.  Also, the notion that the "extension" of a file in any way indicates what application(s) should be used to open it is very Windows-oriented.  Linux has always followed the "magic number" approach of putting a distinctive signature in the first few bytes of a file, and then allowing the name to be anything.  By way of analogy, I were a file in a Windows system, I'd have to be "Monty Harder.human" in order for anything to know what I am, but Linux sees that as part of my content, and the name is unconstrained.

Comment: If you can locate the correct source code you can also locate the committer.

Comment: @Monty Linux has never followed any specific approach for file types; the `file` “magic” technique is retro-fitted and doesn’t always work well. MacOS (the classic variant, I don’t know about macOS) had real “magic” numbers associated with applications.

Comment: @StephenKitt Even before Linux, Unix had shebangs and `file` with the `magic` file, so I don't know how "retro-fitted" it is.  MacOS' approach put an explicit file type in the file metadata ("resource fork"), which is stored inside the file but in a separate container.

Comment: @Monty by “retro-fitted” I meant that file formats in Unix aren’t necessarily designed to have a magic number of any kind, and that `file`’s `magic` database is populated by figuring out magic identifiers after the fact. If you limit yourself to shebangs and executables, then yes, scripts start with a “magic” value, although I don’t think most people would call it magic ;-), and binaries start with an identifier, although [that wasn’t initially designed that way either](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6315/79). Some files can’t be identified reliably (look at `file`’s bug list...).

Comment: This is not helpful since the odds of someone wanting to file a bug report *also* being capable of (within a reasonable time such as a few days) and having the time to fix it themselves is very close to zero. A program like `file` probably has a thousand users per such "patch-capable" user.

Comment: @l0b0 I see your point but I do think it's helpful to say that the _best_ (not _only_) way to request a feature involves implementing it yourself, if you can. People who don't have the necessary programming skill can safely ignore this, but people who do will find it useful.

Comment: I don't think this is the best answer to the question. Even if a patch was developed, the asker still wants to know how to get in touch with someone who maintains the project in question, *even if the patch is not likely to be merged*, *even if the chances of the maintainer even bothering to care what the asker has to say are nil*. Otherwise, the patch is surely useless except for the one who wrote it or the one who can find it buried in the depths of the Internet.

Comment: I believe that the wished feature is not doable in practice

Answer (score 12):

You ask:

> What's the correct way to ask for a feature in GNU Linux?

and to answer that, it's important to know that there's no such single thing as "GNU Linux", per se. The GNU Project is a collaborative effort to develop free software. Some of that free software — along with large amounts of *other* free and open source software — is collected by *other* projects: either collaborative, open projects like Fedora* or Debian, or corporate efforts with varying degrees of openness, or even individuals. These collections are called "Linux Distributions" or "GNU/Linux distributions" (there is a political debate there which I won't get into).

In general, if you are interested in **feature** enhancement, the best thing to do is to work with the developer who wrote the software — the distributions have a lot of work to do to just collect the various software and make it work together, and normally would *prefer* those changes to happen "upstream".

So, you did the right thing here — you found the documented upstream source and tried to report there.

It appears, however, that the documented communication methods for the piece of software you are interested in aren't working. In that case, you have several options:

1. Try to find other ways to contact the developers of the software. In this case, most distros include the `file` command originally written by Ian Darwin and nominally housed at http://www.darwinsys.com/file/, with the mailing lists you've mentioned. But like those mailing lists, the main site appears to be down. In this day and age, checking GitHub is a good second step, and I found https://github.com/file/file — which says 
   *Read-only mirror of file CVS repository, updated every half hour. NOTE: do not make pull requests here, nor comment any commits, submit them usual way to bug tracker or to the mailing list.* That's not immediately helpful, but I notice that there *have* been changes to that repo in the past week. So, one possible next move is to see who did those commits and contact them.
2. You could ask the person responsible for the package in the distro you use. For `file` in Fedora, see [this page](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/file). Since they work with the software regularly, they may have other means of contacting the upstream. Depending on the distro, this is best done by filing a bug or by direct contact — you kind of need to know the individual culture. (In Fedora, I'd suggest the [devel mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/admin/lists/devel.lists.fedoraproject.org/).)
3. If you are using a commercial distribution, like Red Hat Enterprise Linux*, you can file a support ticket. As a paying customer, you may be able to influence your vendor to find a solution.
4. If all else fails, the project you're interested might be *dead upstream*. In that case, you can "fork" the project — create your own version, and build a new upstream community around it. If your version is maintained and the other one is dead, it is likely the distributions will follow.

---

* I work on Fedora. And I'm employed by Red Hat.

Comment: "it's important to know that there's no such single thing as "GNU Linux"" – In particular, it is important to realize that Linux has nothing to do with GNU and GNU has nothing to do with Linux. Asking for a Linux feature from the GNU project or asking for a feature for a GNU utility from a Linux developer will most likely be simply ignored.

Comment: Or asking for a feature for a non-GNU utility from either of those.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in your distribution. If the distribution is shipping man-pages that are out of date, you should file a bug against the package that provided it. If you are using debian, you can use a tool such as reportbug to make this simpler.

Comment: No, this isn’t a bug in the distribution: [the upstream man page](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/doc/file.man) still provides the same information.

Comment: In any case, the maintainer of the package in the distribution should know how to file bugs with the original maintainer of the package

Answer (score 3):

```
identify -format %m file.gif[0]
```

> %m   image file format (file magic)

The [0] means the first frame, which could help if you accidentally use it on a video as otherwise it uses ffmpeg libraries to make a temporary copy of each frame.

This only works for images. I don't know how to do it for generic files. <strike>ffmpeg returns 'avc1' for a random mp4 file (other mp4 files may return different strings, and you still have to parse it), and I don't see a way to get from that to 'mp4'. 'avc1' isn't anywhere in /usr/share/mime.</strike>

ffmpeg, or equivalently ffprobe, lists some file formats the demuxer uses at the start of its output. For an mp4 file it says

> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from . . .
>   [. . .]
>   Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661)

for a png it says

> Input #0, png_pipe, from . . .
>   [. . .]
>   Video: png, rgb24(pc)